# How to change the code tinymce generates when adding images and lists?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, tinymce

I'm working on the site of a client. He uses TinyMCE and WordPress's media uploader to write his blog posts and include images. The problem is it's adding garbage attributes when we try to add images and lists. For example, adding a list will generate the following code;

```
<ul>
  <li><span style="font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1.846153846;">Item one,</span></li>
  <li><span style="font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1.846153846;">Item two.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Obviously, I don't want the extra "style" attribute. Also, when adding images, the editor will wrap it around  tags automatically, which we don't want.

My question is, where in the code of TinyMCE and/or Wordpress's image uploader can we change this sort of formatting?

Comment: +1 good question, are you using tinymce version 3 or 4?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea. The code was ripped from wordpress and the previous coders didn't leave that much information.

Comment: in that case i assume it is tinymce 3

Comment: Actually, I just found out we're using version 4. That explains why there's no formatter.js or style plugin.

Comment: ok, in this case the whole thing works a bit different. i have do not have much experience with tinymce 4 by now

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will find this kind of behaviour hardcoded in the tinymce core file `Formatter.js` (classes directory) and the tinymce `style` plugin.

Comment: That might be a problem, because I can't find either the file Formatter.js or the Style plugin.

Comment: you might want to download the tinymce developer package